# XMLHttpRequest POST stuck at readyState 1 after several successive requests against IIS7+Windows 7 Pro

Tags: javascript, ajax, iis-7, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm using JavaScript to send textarea updates back to a server in real-time.  My HTML page uses a single XMLHttpRequest object to POST data to the server asynchronously.  The messages are sent potentially at every onKeyUp event, but because I only use a single XMLHttpRequest object I throttle the requests by only POSTing when the readyState is either 0 (uninitialized) or 4 (loaded).

Against IIS6 on Windows 2003 Server, everything is working fine.  Against IIS7 on Windows 7 Professional, the readyState of my XMLHttpRequest object gets stuck at 1 (initialized) if I type in several characters quickly.

The number of characters I can get in varies from 3 to 20 or so.  If I reload the page, I can enter in a few more characters until I get stuck again.  If I type slowly, then I can enter more characters before I see the problem.  [Could this have anything to do with connection limits on IIS7?]

Also, if I use GET instead of POST, everything works fine (except that GET won't support the length of data I need to send).

Here's a snippet of the important bits of code here.  Anyone have any insight into this problem?  Thanks in advance.

```
var _xml = getXmlHttpRequest();

function getXmlHttpRequest()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    alert ("Upgrade your browser, Fool!");
    return null;
}

function postValue(value)
{   // sends the answer to the server for saving
    if (_xml.readyState == 4 || _xml.readyState == "0")
    {
        var params = "value=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
        _xml.open("post", "save.py", true);
        _xml.onreadystatechange = handlePostValue;
        _xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        _xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", params.length);
        _xml.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        _xml.send(params);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mike - which browsers does this happen in?

Comment: Excellent question, Kev.  I figured this was browser independent, but it's not.  The problem occurs on:

- IE6 on Windows XP
- IE8 on Windows 7
- Google Chrome 1.0 on Windows XP
- Google Chrome 1.0 on Windows 7

The problem does not occur on:

- Firefox 3.5.7 on Ubuntu 9.10 (for Ubuntu Canonical 1.0)

Those results were very surprising to me.  So it looks like only certain browser to web server combinations are problematic.  Sounds like we have a lot of clues so far, but I don't have a solution yet :(

Comment: I notice the same problem happening on my Windows 7 machine with the Google App Engine web server, even though the same client and server code running on my Windows XP machine works fine.  That makes me think that it's nothing to do with the web server.  It's most likely the OS or the computer itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be creating a brand new XMLHttpRequest object for each request.

Comment: I've seen it done both ways, but I wonder if it matters with POSTing.  There's also the question of why it works on one web server (IIS6) and not another (IIS7).  Nevertheless, it's a worthy suggestion.  I'll give it a shot and let you know how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Pointy, but the same problem occurs whether or not I use a new XHR object for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick side note... would you not want better logic to support ActiveX xmlHTTP?

e.g. what about these versions (in descending order of priority)?

```
Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0
Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0
Msxml2.XMLHTTP
Microsoft.XMLHTTP
```

***Update:*** One other option... I know that (at least in the past) some browsers had issues with the initialization of the readyState property... whereby it didn't have a value set.

Does changing this line help?

```
//was
if (_xml.readyState == 4 || _xml.readyState == "0")

//try this
if (typeof(_xml.readyState) == 'undefined' || 
    _xml.readyState == 4 || _xml.readyState == "0")
```

Comment: The baseline `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` is the same as `Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0` in most cases, though Microsoft would prefer you to use the namespace `Msxml2`. You only need to sniff for `6.0` if there's anything in that version you need (like XPath). Probably there isn't. See http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx

Comment: It couldn't hurt to have the latest-and-greatest.  I'll try them out.

Comment: I changed my script to get the latest.  As expected, it didn't help with my problem, which also occurs on Google Chrome which uses the proper XMLHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 0):

I could skip the parameter problem for a short time. I have currently 3 form parameters to send. I devide them by using a character that shows wich form stack element was hit, a numeric to show wich part of that stac was hit and a boolean for another reason.